# ipython Qtconsole - conflicting keybinding

Tags: ipython

The `ipython` [documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/interactive/qtconsole.html) says, that "The qt-console has emacs-style keybindings"

However, when I press <kbd>Ctrl+w</kbd>, instead of the expected emacs-style keybinding (delete word backward), my session/window is closed

is this intended behavior?

<kbd>Ctrl+w</kbd> is the most useful emacs-style keybinding. I find it very unfortunate that somebody has decided to hijacke it for "close window"

Is there any way to reset it back to emacs-style

Comment: That should probably say *some* emacs-style keybindings. I don't think it's supposed to be the full set.

Comment: @Thomas K - OK, but who needs keyboard shortcut to close the window? And why highjack the most useful shortcut (`Ctrl+w`) for that ? The idea of Keyboard shortcuts is to simplify actions which are performed many times, not for once-per-session action such as closing the window. Using `Ctrl+w` for that is really unfortunate.

Comment: I use Ctrl-W to close tabs in my browser and editor, and I didn't even know what it did in emacs. What's intuitive and useful is subjective.

Comment: @Thomas K - I don't know what editor and browser you are using, but it definitely does not have emacs-style keybindings.

Comment: In our docs, I suspect 'emacs style keybindings' just means ctrl+foo shortcuts, as opposed to vi style modal shortcuts.

Comment: @Thomas K - I am not sure what you mean. `Ctrl+w` is an Emacs shortcut to "kill word backwards". In my mind, it does not make any sense to use it to close window.

Comment: Yes. I think you're reading 'emacs-style' as promising much more similarity to emacs than it was actually meant to. Maybe it should be reworded.

Comment: @Thomas K - why not changing the binding for 'Ctrl-w` to its proper function, rather than rewording the documentation. After all, qt-console is a "console" so it would be logical for it to behave as a console (and not as a web browser).

Comment: The 'proper function' is not unambiguously the one you want. It's not just web browsers that use ctrl-w for closing a tab/document - it's fairly common in editors, and I see it in xchat as well. My terminal emulator uses Ctrl-Shift-W for closing a tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the answer you were looking for, but I am pretty sure this is not possible.  The document you point to says "The Qt frontend has hand-coded emacs-style bindings for text navigation. This is not yet configurable."  The fact that they are hand coded means that there is no default emacs-style binding set to "revert" back to.